# Game Center default match maker view controller does not show existing matches much of the time

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, gkturnbasedmatch

I am creating a turn-based match for iOS using Game Center using Swift. My test devices are running iOS 8.3. I am using the standard (non-custom) view controller provided by Game center (GKTurnBasedMatchmakerViewController) to interface with Game Center.

When I start my app, first it automatically authenticates with Game Center. Then I press a button on my interface and pull up the matchmaker view controller. About 1/3 of the time, when I display this matchmaker view controller, it does not load and does not show my existing Game Center matches, instead it goes straight to Auto Match. Other times, it finds them just fine.  If it doesn't show them, if I cancel the view controller and pull it up again, it usually finds them on the second try. Note that I am able to authenticate my local player with Game Center so I don't *think( that is the problem.

What is the reason for this issue? Is there something running in the background talking to Game Center that has not finished at the time I try to bring up the view controller? And is there a remedy or workaround?

Comment: At what point in the application lifecycle are you authenticating the localPlayer? And are are you verifying that the authentication succeeded before doing the other gc stuff like with the matchmaker vc etc?

Comment: I authenticate immediately upon starting the app.  I did not force verification programmatically to check whether the authentication succeeded before doing the other GC stuff, but the issues I report are after I start up and I am notified by GC: "Welcome back, (local player name)".  The notification code is in my authenticateHandler.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm not being accurate with the GC and iOS terminology.  In the cases where I am not connected to Game Center, it will tell me that it is not connected and not allow any GC view controller to come up. In my case, I can get a GC view controller, but it is the Automatch view controller (the default when there are no existing matches).  Is it something like, the Game Center user information is cached, allowing the welcome notification to  occur, but that I am not yet actually connected?